# JS - Same regex, different result on the same string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I see a different result of a javascript regex on 2 different servers and also on the Internet.

I have this string :

```
000|Hello
100|1234999|1
999|3
```

And here is my regex:

```
/(?:(?<=[^][9]{3}[|][0-9]*)[\n](?=.)|[\n](?=000))/g
```

On the internet (https://regex101.com) I have a result = "true" at the end of the second line.

On my PROD environment under node.js in version 8.10.0, I get the same result.

On other DEV environment (configured under the same version of node.js and with the exact same javascript code) I get a result = false.

Here is the code in question:

```
var msg = "000|Hello\n100|1234999|1\n999|3\n";
var reg = /(?:(?<=[^][9]{3}[|][0-9]*)[\n](?=.)|[\n](?=000))/g
if(msg.search(reg) != -1)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

I'm looking for ways to understand where the difference in result can come from when I use the same regex, on the same string, and this under the same version of node.js

---

EDIT :

My regex should split the message if a line 000 which is not the first line is found or if a line is found after a line 999.

For example :

```
000|Hello
100|1234999|1
000|World
```

or

```
000|Hello
100|1234999|1
999|3
100|12345
```

To put it in context, I have to change the beginning of my regex `[^]` by `[\n]`, since the message was split at the wrong place. But since I don't reproduce the error (regex = true) on my DEV/Test environments, I can't qualify my fix correctly (although I'm sure of my modification).

Is the Javascript version the same if the node.js version is the same? If not, how to know the Javascript version used?

Comment: It must be due to the lookbehind, which isn't supported in all versions of JavaScript.

Comment: In your case, it looks like you don't need lookaround at all.

Comment: Your regex is needlessly convoluted. It would help if you wrote in plain English what exactly you are looking for in that string.

Comment: Check CRLF/CR/LF endings, `(?<=[^]9{3}\|[0-9]*)(?:\r\n?|\n)(?=.)|(?:\r\n?|\n)(?=000)`, [like here](https://regex101.com/r/RjbfTs/1).

Comment: I checked but it doesn't seem to come from there @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Are node.js versions the same? Up-to-date on both servers? Old versions might not support infinite-width lookbehinds.

Comment: Like I said, the version is 8.10.0 on both servers. That's why I don't understand.